# Removing decimal places from computed field in VB Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i have the following Table;

```
ID   Integer
CTN length   Decimal

CTN width    Decimal

CTN height   Decimal

Room width   Decimal

Room Length  Decimal

Room Height  Decimal

CTNs Width   Decimal    Computed field = Room Width / CTN width
```

for example the result of computed field is `12.80`

I want to remove the decimal places from the result so the result will be only 12    without any fractions

anybody knows how to do that in VB light switch?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to remain a decimal, just with no decimals after the decimal point, you can use:

```
Int(Computed field = Room Width / CTN width)
```

If you also want the value to be converted to an integer:

```
Cint(Int(Computed field = Room Width / CTN width))
```

These links give more details:

[Conversion.Int Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.int%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Type Conversion Functions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VB.CINT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)